# Checking file size in makefile, stopping if file is too short

Tags: compilation, makefile

Is there a way to check if the size of a particular file is less than some constant? I'm assuming things about size in the makefile and want to make sure I'll get an error if my assumptions are not met. Something like assert, but in makefile.

```
if filesize(file) > C then error
else continue compilation
```

Comment: What brand/version of make are you using? I'm not aware of anything standard for this, so you'll probably have to shell out - what OS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this in your rule, somewhere before the compilation:

```
 test -n "$$(find filename -a -size +NNNc)"
```

where `filename` is the filename and `NNN` is the size in octets. This returns false and halts `make` when the size is less than or equal to `NNN`.

Answer (score 2):

My approach for this, is probably not the most pretty solution, but it worked for me :)

```
CHECKFILE = \
    if [ ! -f "file" ]; then \
        echo "file does not exist" ; exit 1 ; \
    fi; \
    FSIZE=$$(du -b "file" | cut -f 1) ; \
    if [ $$FSIZE -lt 100000 ]; then \
        echo "filesize too small" ; exit 1 ; \
    fi

all:
    @$(CHECKFILE)
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this-- continue if greater than 256 bytes, otherwise stop make-- for readability:

```
test `wc -c <$<` -gt 256;
```

Within the backticks, the file `$<` is directed into `wc -c`, which returns the size in bytes of `$<`.   After the backticks evaluate the size of `$<`, `test` is then used with the `-gt` "greater than" operator.