# Makefile object files not created

Tags: makefile

Have you ever experienced a situation when an object file was not present after successful compilation?

Running on windows using gnumake-4.2.1 and gcc-arm-none-eabi-5_4-2016q3 toolchain
I have a makefile which I am not full author of

this is interesting part

```
DEPFLAGS =  -MT $@ -MMD -MP -MF $@.d

$(OBJS_OUTPUT_FOLDER)/%.o : %.cpp
    @$(CXX) -c $< -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $(DEPFLAGS) $(INC_FOLDERS_INT) $(LANGUAGE_STANDARD_CPP) \
    && echo $@ OK && $(CP) $@ C:/build/
```

and this is the console output

```
build/bar.o OK
build/baz.o OK
build/foo.o OK
cp: can't stat 'build/foo.o': No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [Makefile:223: build/foo.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Checking the file system shows that the foo.o really is not present, sometimes other files are missing as well (for example baz.o.d).
I don't really think its fault of the makefile because it gets done eventually (usually on the second to third try without cleaning).

When all of the objects are done I usually get linker error

```
aaa.hh:183: undefined reference to `MyNamespace::MyFun(short, short, short)'
```

MyFun is not in bar, baz neither in foo. The object file that should contain  MyFun is present, but the size of it is total nonsense (556B), but if I manually delete it (as suggested elsewhere on SO when dealing with undefined references (as a corrupted one)) and make all again it gets done (now the size is around 1.5MB) and creates the binary.

Edit:
As the incorrect files have stable size (well, for the time being it seems so) I have added

```
 @test `wc -c <$@` -ne 556;
```

to the rule([Checking file size in makefile, stopping if file is too short](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673189/checking-file-size-in-makefile-stopping-if-file-is-too-short)), this catches the wrong objects (I know specific case) and together with .DELETE_ON_ERROR: I don't have to manually delete the bad ones I find after linking the output of the console in this case is

```
[ CXX ] build/bar.o
make[1]: *** [Makefile:219: build/bar.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** Deleting file 'build/bar.o'
```

while in the other case

```
[ CXX ] build/foo.o
/spt/resources/sh: can't open build/foo.o: no such file
sh: 556: unknown operand
make[1]: *** [Makefile:220: build/foo.o] Error 2
```

so it probably is not makefile deleting it (I believe it would announce it as in the first case)

Edit2:
After setting a virtual machine (Windows 7) and making the project again (same makefile, same toolchain, same make) it goes smoothly. I guess there really is something on the host computer, maybe an antivirus or some other corporate security software...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you remove the `@` from `@$(CXX)` so that you can check the actual command being run.

Comment: Yes, the resulting command is same in both cases    ../SPT/RESOURCES/gcc-arm-none-eabi-5_4-2016q3/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc -c bar.c -o build/bar.o -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mlittle-endian -mthumb-interwork -Werror -Og -g3 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -DHSE_VALUE=16000000 -DSTM32F437xx -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DFREERTOS_CONFIG_STM32F4 -Wall -Werror -MT build/bar.o -MMD -MP -MF build/bar.o.d -I(LONG_LIST_OF_INCLUDES_THAT_WONT_FIT_HERE) -std=gnu11 \
 && echo bar.o OK && ../SPT/RESOURCES/busybox cp build/bar.o C:/build/

Comment: Could it be that you have a space after the \ in @$(CXX) ... \?